# SQLException при подключении к Oracle через JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Есть класс:

```
public class DataSource {

    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No driver");
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

При обращении к методу выбрасывается `SQLException`. Через sqlplus подключаюсь без проблем.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы смотрели текст выдаваемого `SQLException`? "Unable to connect" не очень информативно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @Regent! Действительно, проблема возникла из-за   NLS_LANG, помогло добавление параметров VM. -Duser.country=en -Duser.language=en